# SQL SubQuery Left Join

Tags: sql-server, join, subquery

I'm writing a SQL Query but having difficulty with my joins / sub-query.
I have a tasks table that i want to join to another table 'tbl_Profile_Mortgage'
The problem is that the tasks table has multiple duplicated clientID's so join them brings back all the including the duplicate. I have modified it to only look at the client Id's that have a 'taskid = originatorId'
This works fine however i want to create another join to show a column in my tasks table but because i have done the join in the tasks table as a sub-query i cant reference the tasks column. Hope this is making sense.
I have commented out the join i would like to add and the column id like to show. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

```css
SELECT 
pm.DateCompleted AS DateCompleted,
pm.DateAppRcvd AS DateAppRcvd,
pm.DatePAckaged AS DatePackaged,
pm.DateOffered AS DateOffered,
pm.DateAppIssued AS DateAppIssued,
pm.DatePassed AS DatePassed,
pm.DateCancelled AS DateCancelled,
pm.DateOfEnquiry AS DateOfEnquiry,
pm.Arrangementfee,
pm.Lender,
pm.DateDip,
cf.ClNTNME,
pm.dateDeclined,
pm.Procfeeexp,
pm.fk_ProfileId,
u.FullName AS Advisor,   
pm.Source,
pm.AmountRequested,
c.CaseTypeDesc,
cf.ClientId,
--ISD.ISDESC,
pm.AmountRequested,
pl.SiteNameNum,
pl.SiteAddr1,
pl.SiteAddr2,
pl.SiteTown,
pl.SiteCounty,
pl.SitePostcode
FROM  dbo.tbl_Profile_Mortgage AS pm
 LEFT JOIN dbo.tbl_ClientFile AS cf
  ON cf.ClientID = pm.ClientId
 LEFT JOIN tbl_Profile_ProjectLand AS pl
  ON pl.FK_ProfileId = pm.FK_ProfileId
 LEFT JOIN tbl_User AS u
  ON u.UserId = pm.UpdatedBy
 LEFT JOIN dbo.tbl_CaseTypes AS c
  ON c.CaseTypeId = pm.CaseType
 LEFT JOIN 
  (
  SELECT Distinct ClientId
   FROM Tasks 
   WHERE TaskId = OriginatorId 
      )t
  ON (t.clientid =  pm.ClientId)
 --LEFT JOIN dbo.tbl_DDInitialSource AS ISD
 -- ON t.EnquirySource = ISD.ISId
```

Comment: Depends on the data relation between ClientID and EnquirySource within the tasks subquery join (table t in the query). If the EnquirySource is the same for every duplicated instance of ClientID then just add any sensible aggregate to the subquery. eg. SELECT Distinct ClientId, MAX(EnquirySource) FROM Tasks. If, however, they aren't the same, then you'll need to determine how to end up with a single "answer" (MIN, MAX, MEAN etc etc).

Answer (score 0):

So I have taken Dave Brown suggestion of adding max to the sub Query and it works perfectly thanks Dave

```css
SELECT 
pm.DateCompleted AS DateCompleted,
pm.DateAppRcvd AS DateAppRcvd,
pm.DatePAckaged AS DatePackaged,
pm.DateOffered AS DateOffered,
pm.DateAppIssued AS DateAppIssued,
pm.DatePassed AS DatePassed,
pm.DateCancelled AS DateCancelled,
pm.DateOfEnquiry AS DateOfEnquiry,
pm.Arrangementfee,
pm.Lender,
pm.DateDip,
--cf.ClNTNME,
pm.dateDeclined,
pm.Procfeeexp,
pm.fk_ProfileId,
u.FullName AS Advisor,              
pm.Source,
pm.AmountRequested,
--c.CaseTypeDesc,
cf.ClientId,
ISD.ISDESC,
pm.AmountRequested,
pl.SiteNameNum,
pl.SiteAddr1,
pl.SiteAddr2,
pl.SiteTown,
pl.SiteCounty,
pl.SitePostcode
FROM  dbo.tbl_Profile_Mortgage AS pm
LEFT JOIN dbo.tbl_ClientFile AS cf
    ON cf.ClientID = pm.ClientId
LEFT JOIN tbl_Profile_ProjectLand AS pl
    ON pl.FK_ProfileId = pm.FK_ProfileId
LEFT JOIN tbl_User AS u
    ON u.UserId = pm.UpdatedBy
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT DISTINCT ClientID, MAX(enquirySource) AS enquirySource
             FROM Tasks 
  GROUP BY clientID
    ) AS t
    ON t.clientid =  pm.ClientId
LEFT JOIN dbo.tbl_DDInitialSource AS ISD
    ON t.EnquirySource = ISD.ISId
```